# Android invalidateDrawable() not working

Tags: android, android-drawable, statelistdrawable, android-view-invalidate

I have a bunch of drawables in a custom view. I want the user to be able to press on one or multiple drawables and it changes colors. Currently, each drawable is just a `StateListDrawable` with two states: `state_pressed` and not pressed. Every time I press a drawable, `setState` returns true so I'm assuming that it is actually changed, but I don't see the drawable image change. Is `invalidateDrawable` not doing anything? What am I doing wrong? How can I redraw the one drawable when pressed without needing call `customView.invalidate()` and redrawing the whole thing each time? I was doing that originally but found that my app ran very slowly/inefficiently. Thanks!

The flow:

```
Custom View (contains set of our custom class - TouchKey)
- Custom class TouchKey containing drawable and info
- Upon press or release, custom class finds which drawable to change
```

Here's code for a button touch within `TouchKey` class (MyTouch is a custom class tracking all the touches on the android device):

```
public void pressed(MyTouch touch) {
    boolean successfulStateChange = this.drawable.setState(new int[]{android.
                                                           R.attr.state_pressed});
    this.customView.invalidateDrawable(drawable);
}

public void released(MyTouch touch) {
    boolean successfulStateChange = this.drawable.setState(new int[]{-android.
                                                           R.attr.state_pressed});
    this.customView.invalidateDrawable(drawable);
}
```

How my `StateListDrawable` is being drawn in my custom view:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private TreeMap<Integer, TouchKey> keymap;

    /* Initialization Code Stuff Here - call drawKey */

    // StateListDrawable Creation
    private StateListDrawable drawKey(Canvas canvas, int bounds_l, 
                                  int bounds_t, int bounds_r, int bounds_b) 
        throws Resources.NotFoundException, XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        StateListDrawable key = new StateListDrawable();
        key.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, 
                     ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.key_pressed));
        key.addState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_pressed}, 
                     ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.key_released));    

        key.setBounds(bound_l, bounds_t, bounds_r, bounds_b);
        key.draw(canvas);

        return key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was doing that originally but found that my app ran very slowly/inefficiently

If do it so you have a big advantages in some place in your code, or (I suppose) doesn't scale images before drawing. So try to find a logic on your code that have a huge advantage on system. Because `View.invalidate()` so fast method.

Other 0,02$ :

I suppose that you develop something like a keyboard. For this case you need invalidate just region of your canvas.

```
View.invalidate(new Rect(0, 0, 49, 49));
```

Comment: Hi ssh, what do you mean in your first sentence, just having a little trouble understanding it. And I tried to invalidate the rect but I'm still achieving very slow times

Comment: @yun.cloud I mean that you have a long playing work in UI thread. Maybe it dialogs, or progressbar's or similar like this. Spent a little bit time to inspect your code with the question "What the hard logic in this method/class?" If you sure that problem not here try to inspect your code via DDMS tools and look what is going on in your system. Why you have a lags?

Comment: Well I do have a audio thread running the whole time the app is running so it's probably that? I guess this is important so each time a drawable is pressed a sine wave is played. When I don't have to redraw each time, multitouch is fine. However, trying to put in the redrawing of each pressed drawable slows down tracking - sometimes when 3 drawables are pressed at the same time, two change/play immediately while the 3rd one takes a bit longer to play/change color. I'm guessing this lag has more to do on my end with the audio processing slowing things down?

Comment: @yun.cloud it may produce lags if you prepare every sound or load it from filesystem. I suppose you do that in UI thread.

Comment: Well I'm running my audio threading in Open SLES, so could that be it? I just tested it without the audio thread running and the touches still lag (same problem but without sound)

Comment: @yun.cloud open DDMS and inspect for allocation. Maybe it hard, but i'm pretty sure that you have a complex problem

Comment: I tested on a different Android device (a newer model, the one I was using is a Samsung Galaxy Tablet 3) today. All multitouches/lags I experienced on my usual testing device was basically gone. I'm guessing that some devices cannot process as quickly and efficiently as the other ones. To remedy this, I put two modes - a low and high speed mode where the low has the color change and the high has no color change. I know this isn't the best work around but is a better solution for right now as there are so many android devices and I can't test on all of them. Marking this as correct answer! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem too, but I solve it in the end. The reason for this problem is that the `Drawable` object which you are using in the context doesn't setup it's `Bounds` by call `setBounds(Rect)`, so it's `Bounds` is `Rect(0,0,0,0)` by default. This cause `invalidateDrawable()` of `View` which `Drawable` attached not working.

See the `View.invalidateDrawable()`:

```
@Override
public void invalidateDrawable(@NonNull Drawable drawable) {
    if (verifyDrawable(drawable)) {
        final Rect dirty = drawable.getDirtyBounds();
        final int scrollX = mScrollX;
        final int scrollY = mScrollY;

        invalidate(dirty.left + scrollX, dirty.top + scrollY,
                dirty.right + scrollX, dirty.bottom + scrollY);
        rebuildOutline();
    }
}
```

Look check Drawable.getDirtyBounds():

```
  /**
 * Return the drawable's dirty bounds Rect. Note: for efficiency, the
 * returned object may be the same object stored in the drawable (though
 * this is not guaranteed).
 * <p>
 * By default, this returns the full drawable bounds. Custom drawables may
 * override this method to perform more precise invalidation.
 *
 * @return The dirty bounds of this drawable
 */
@NonNull
public Rect getDirtyBounds() {
    return getBounds();
}
```

So the **Rect dirty** is `Rect(0,0,0,0)`, if you not setup `Drawable.Bounds`.Therefore `View.invalidate()` doesn't working.

**So what you have to do is** setup `Drawable.Bounds` in some place in the code，like that：

```
@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    Rect localRect = canvas.getClipBounds();
    this.setBounds(localRect);
    ...
}
```